# C++: STL troubles with const class members

Tags: c++

It is an open ended question.
Effective C++. Item 3. **Use const whenever possible.** Really?

I would like to make anything which doesn't change during the objects lifetime const. But const comes with it own troubles. If a class has any const member, the compiler generated assignment operator is disabled. Without an assignment operator a class won't work with STL. If you want to provide your own assignment operator, **const_cast** is required. That means more hustle and more room for error. How often you use const class members?

**EDIT:** As a rule, I strive for const correctness because I do a lot of multithreading. I rarely need to implemented copy control for my classes and never code delete (unless it is absolutely necessary). I feel that the current state of affairs with const contradicts my coding style. Const forces me to implement assignment operator even though I don't need one. Even without **const_cast** assignment is a hassle. You need to make sure that all const members compare equal and then manually copy all non-const member.

**Code.** Hope it will clarify what I mean. The class you see below won't work with STL. You need to implement an assignment for it, even though you don't need one.

```
class Multiply {
public:
    Multiply(double coef) : coef_(coef) {}
    double operator()(double x) const {
        return coef_*x;
    }
private:
    const double coef_;
};
```

Comment: Can you write a simple example of what you're trying to do ?

Comment: @Scharron It's quite clear what he's asking about, to me at least.

Comment: @Scharron I think he wants to make the question more general by not giving one

Comment: In this case, using `const` isn't possible, since the member needs to be assignable.

Comment: @Mike It is possible - you just need to implement the assignment op and copy ctor yourself.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: There's normally no need to do anything about the *copy constructor* specifically. Const members don't affect implicit copy constructors. They only affect implicit copy assignment operators.

Comment: @Neil: modifying a `const` object is undefined behaviour; I don't think there's an exception for data members (but please correct me if there is). If you need to assign to it, then it shouldn't be `const`, even if your implementation happens to do what you expect when you use `const_cast`.

Comment: I think we've got a misunderstanding of "whenever possible" here.

Comment: @Mike You simply write the assignment op so it does not change the const object.

Comment: Don't use const *members*, use const *objects*.

Comment: @Mike: AFAIK const variables aren't const objects. For example, literals are const objects; but modifying a const variable is only undefined if it represents a const object.

Comment: @Neil: "write the assignment op so it does not change the const object" - if you can do that, then fine. But the question says that `const_cast` is required, presumably to change the `const` object, in which case the member shouldn't be `const`.

Comment: @Philipp: members of a class object are also objects; if they're declared `const` then they are `const` objects, and changing them gives undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Mike: Indeed, I seem to have confused const objects with pointers to const that point to non-const objects. (§7.1.6.1.4)

Comment: +1 because you provided the example for a question about what is, anyway, some kind of confusing corner of C++

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As AndreyT pointed out, under these circumstances assignment (mostly) doesn't make a lot of sense. The problem is that `vector` (for one example) is kind of an exception to that rule.

Logically, you copy an object into the `vector`, and sometime later you get back another copy of the original object. From a purely logical viewpoint, there's no assignment involved. The problem is that `vector` requires that the object be assignable anyway (actually, all C++ containers do). It's basically making an implementation detail (that somewhere in its code, it might assign the objects instead of copying them) part of the interface.

There is no simple cure for this. Even defining your own assignment operator and using `const_cast` doesn't really fix the problem. It's perfectly safe to use `const_cast` when you get a `const` pointer or reference to an object that you know isn't actually defined to be `const`. In this case, however, the variable itself *is* defined to be `const` -- attempting to cast away the `const`ness and assign to it gives undefined behavior. In reality, it'll almost always work anyway (as long as it's not `static const` with an initializer that's known at compile time), but there's no guarantee of it.

C++ 11 and newer add a few new twists to this situation. In particular, objects no longer *need* to be assignable to be stored in a vector (or other collections). It's sufficient that they be movable. That doesn't help in this particular case (it's no easier to move a `const` object than it is to assign it) but does make life substantially easier in some other cases (i.e., there are certainly types that are movable but not assignable/copyable).

In this case, you *could* use a move rather than a copy by adding a level of indirection. If your create an "outer" and an "inner" object, with the `const` member in the inner object, and the outer object just containing a pointer to the inner:

```
struct outer { 
    struct inner {
        const double coeff;
    };

    inner *i;
};
```

...then when we create an instance of `outer`, we define an `inner` object to hold the `const` data. When we need to do an assignment, we do a typical move assignment: copy the pointer from the old object to the new one, and (probably) set the pointer in the old object to a nullptr, so when it's destroyed, it won't try to destroy the inner object.

If you wanted to badly enough, you could use (sort of) the same technique in older versions of C++. You'd still use the outer/inner classes, but each assignment would allocate a whole new inner object, or you'd use something like a shared_ptr to let the outer instances share access to a single inner object, and clean it up when the last outer object is destroyed.

It doesn't make any real difference, but at least for the assignment used in managing a vector, you'd only have two references to an `inner` while the `vector` was resizing itself (resizing is why a vector requires assignable to start with).

Answer (score 19):

You said yourself that you make const "anything which doesn't change during the objects lifetime". Yet you complain about the implicitly declared assignment operator getting disabled. But implicitly declared assignment operator *does* change the contents of the member in question! It is perfectly logical (according to your own logic) that it is getting disabled. Either that, or you shouldn't be declaring that member const.

Also, providing you own assignment operator does not require a `const_cast`. Why? Are you trying to *assign* to the member you declared const inside your assignment operator? If so, why did you declare it const then?

In other words, provide a more meaningful description of the problems you are running into. The one you provided so far is self-contradictory in the most obvious manner.

Comment: So all the answers suggesting to remove the const once you need to perform assignment may be suggesting the right thing.

Comment: +1: Is the member const, or isn't it? If you can change it by assigning another instance of your class to it, then it's not const.

Comment: Try to use logical const objects with STL and see what.

Comment: @rn141: Try to provide the code that is a problem for you. This will avoid misunderstandings.

Comment: @rn141: This is a different (albeit also interesting) issue that has nothing to do with the topic. The topic is about the *internal* constness, which is not necessarily exposed through the external interface. I.e. it is not about "logical const objects".

Comment: @rn141: Logically constant objects have only const methods (except for assignment). Who cares if the members are const or not?

Comment: It is not about correctness or efficiency. Personally I find the current behavior of const non-intuitive and too draconian. Assignment should be allowed unless the whole class is const. At least it makes more seance to me than the current state of affairs.

Comment: @rn141: default assignment isn't allowed because it would change a `const` object, and `const` objects can't be changed.

Comment: @rn141: and the solution is to fix the containers, not change the meaning of `const`. In C++0x, containers won't require objects to be assignable.

Comment: @Mike: So objects can be *move*-assignable instead? This doesn't have the exact same problem?

Comment: @UncleBens: no, they need to be copy- or move-*constructible*, not assignable, when necessary. There's no problem with constructing an object with `const` members, just with assigning to it.

Answer (score 5):

I very rarely use them - the hassle is too great. Of course I always strive for const correctness when it comes to member functions, parameters or return types.

Answer (score 4):

Errors at compile time are painful, but errors at runtime are deadly. Constructions using const might be a hassle to code, but it might help you find bugs before you implement them. I use consts whenever possible.

Comment: Good general advice, but in this case the cost of having `const` members is to have to maintain the assignment operator, which can also lead to deadly bugs.

Answer (score 3):

I try my best to follow the advice of using `const` whenever possible, however I agree that when it comes to class members, `const` is a big hassle.

I have found that I am very careful with `const`-correctness when it comes to parameters, but not as much with class members.  Indeed, when I make class members `const` and it results in an error (due to using STL containers), the first thing I do is remove the `const`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm wondering about your case... Everything below is but supposition because you did not provide the example code describing your problem, so...

### The cause

I guess you have something like:

```
struct MyValue
{
   int         i ;
   const int   k ;
} ;
```

IIRC, the default assignment operator will do a member-by-member assignment, which is akin to :

```
MyValue & operator = (const MyValue & rhs)
{
   this->i = rhs.i ;
   this->k = rhs.k ; // THIS WON'T WORK BECAUSE K IS CONST
   return *this ;
} ;
```

Thus, this won't get generated.

So, your problem is that without this assignment operator, the STL containers won't accept your object.

As far I as see it:

1. The compiler is right to not generate this `operator =`
2. You should provide your own, because only you know exactly what you want

### You solution

I'm afraid to understand what do you mean by `const_cast`.

My own solution to your problem would be to write the following user defined operator :

```
MyValue & operator = (const MyValue & rhs)
{
   this->i = rhs.i ;
   // DON'T COPY K. K IS CONST, SO IT SHOULD NO BE MODIFIED.
   return *this ;
} ;
```

This way, if you'll have:

```
MyValue a = { 1, 2 }, b = {10, 20} ;
a = b ; // a is now { 10, 2 }
```

As far as I see it, it is coherent. But I guess, reading the `const_cast` solution, that you want to have something more like:

```
MyValue a = { 1, 2 }, b = {10, 20} ;
a = b ; // a is now { 10, 20 } :  K WAS COPIED
```

Which means the following code for `operator =`:

```
MyValue & operator = (const MyValue & rhs)
{
   this->i = rhs.i ;
   const_cast<int &>(this->k) = rhs.k ;
   return *this ;
} ;
```

But, then, you wrote in your question:

> I would like to make anything which doesn't change during the objects lifetime const

With what I supposed is your own `const_cast` solution, k changed during the object lifetime, which means that you contradict yourself because **you need a member variable that doesn't change during the object lifetime *unless you want it to change***!

### The solution

Accept the fact your member variable will change during the lifetime of its owner object, and remove the const.

Comment: Even if I don't need an assignment operator, STL forces me to implement one.

Comment: @rn141: By reading your comments, I understand that, 1., you use const as a guarantee the value won't be changed (and thus, no need of locks or atomic semantics when reading the value across threads), and 2., you want to avoid having an assignment operator on your objects......... I suspect you are giving us a lot less information than we need to evaluate your problem and then offer possible solutions.

Comment: @rn141: Anyway, the fact you used a const_cast to modify the const value means there are something wrong, a difference between the way you think to code will work, and the way it will really work. And if this is tied to multithreading safety, bugs will become really interesting.

Comment: @rn141: Still, I understand your viewpoint, but you are using value semantics (you are putting values inside STL containers), which means that with those value semantics comes the necessity of copy/assignment... If you want to avoid copy/assignment, then value semantics is not for you..... In this case, you should switch from value semantics to reference/pointer semantics. Instead of putting values inside STL containers, put pointers to those values (or better, smart pointers). This way, you can move your objects, while still having their values (or part of their values) remain constant.

Answer (score 2):

you can store `shared_ptr` to your `const` objects in STL containers if you'd like to retain `const` members.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/utility.hpp>

#include <vector>

class Fruit : boost::noncopyable
{
public:
    Fruit( 
            const std::string& name
         ) :
        _name( name )
    {

    }

    void eat() const { std::cout << "eating " << _name << std::endl; }

private:
    const std::string _name;
};

int
main()
{
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<const Fruit> FruitPtr;
    typedef std::vector<FruitPtr> FruitVector;
    FruitVector fruits;
    fruits.push_back( boost::make_shared<Fruit>("apple") );
    fruits.push_back( boost::make_shared<Fruit>("banana") );
    fruits.push_back( boost::make_shared<Fruit>("orange") );
    fruits.push_back( boost::make_shared<Fruit>("pear") );
    BOOST_FOREACH( const FruitPtr& fruit, fruits ) {
        fruit->eat();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

though, as others have pointed out it's somewhat of a hassle and often easier in my opinion to remove the const qualified members if you desire the compiler generated copy constructor.

Comment: And shared_ptr will add some overhead due to reference counting.

Comment: Less efficient and more hassle.

Answer (score 1):

I only use const on reference or pointer class members. I use it to indicate that the target of the reference or pointer should not be changed. Using it on other kinds of class members is a big hassle as you found out.

The best places to use const is in function parameters, pointers and references of all kinds, constant integers and temporary convenience values.

An example of a temporary convenience variable would be:

```
char buf[256];
char * const buf_end = buf + sizeof(buf);
fill_buf(buf, buf_end);
const size_t len = strlen(buf);
```

That `buf_end` pointer should never point anywhere else so making it const is a good idea. The same idea with `len`. If the string inside `buf` never changes in the rest of the function then its `len` should not change either. If I could, I would even change `buf` to const after calling `fill_buf`, but C/C++ does not let you do that.

Answer (score 1):

The point is that the poster wants `const` protection within his implementation but still wants the object assignable. The language does not support such semantics conveniently as constness of the member resides at the same logical level and is tightly coupled with assignability.

However, the `pImpl` idiom with a reference counted implementation or smart pointer will do exactly what the poster wants as assignability is then moved out of the implementation and up a level to the higher level object. The implementation object is only constructed/destructed whence assignment is never needed at the lower level.

Answer (score 0):

I think your statement

> If a class has const any member, the
>   compiler generated assignment operator
>   is disabled.

Might be incorrect. I have classes that have const method

```
bool is_error(void) const;
....
virtual std::string info(void) const;
....
```

that are also used with STLs. So perhaps your observation is compiler dependent or only applicable to the member variables?

Comment: We are talking about const data members, not functions.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't too hard.  You shouldn't have any trouble making your own assignment operator.  The const bits don't need to be assigned (as they're const).

**Update**
There is some misunderstanding about what const means.  It means that it will not change, ever.

If an assignment is supposed to change it, then it isn't const.
If you just want to prevent others changing it, make it private and don't provide an update method.
**End Update**

```
class CTheta
{
public:
    CTheta(int nVal)
    : m_nVal(nVal), m_pi(3.142)
    {
    }
    double GetPi() const { return m_pi; }
    int GetVal()   const { return m_nVal; }
    CTheta &operator =(const CTheta &x)
    {
        if (this != &x)
        {
            m_nVal = x.GetVal();
        }
        return *this;
    }
private:
    int m_nVal;
    const double m_pi;
};

bool operator < (const CTheta &lhs, const CTheta &rhs)
{
    return lhs.GetVal() < rhs.GetVal();
}
int main()
{
    std::vector<CTheta> v;
    const size_t nMax(12);

    for (size_t i=0; i<nMax; i++)
    {
        v.push_back(CTheta(::rand()));
    }
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    std::vector<CTheta>::const_iterator itr;
    for (itr=v.begin(); itr!=v.end(); ++itr)
    {
        std::cout << itr->GetVal() << " " << itr->GetPi() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: of course, in this (and many) examples, `m_pi` should be `static`.

Comment: @rlbond -- Yes, it possibly should be.  It is just a simplistic example and I needed a const value to illustrate the point.

Comment: After **x = y** you may end up with **x !=y **. If const fields aren't equal, assignment should fail.

Answer (score 0):

I would only use const member iff the class itself is non-copyable. I have many classes that I declare with boost::noncopyable

```
class Foo : public boost::noncopyable {
    const int x;
    const int y;
}
```

However if you want to be very sneaky and cause yourself lots of potential
problems you can effect a copy construct without an assignment but you have to
be a bit careful.

```
#include <new>
#include <iostream>
struct Foo {
    Foo(int x):x(x){}
    const int x;
    friend std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & os, Foo const & f ){
         os << f.x;
         return os;
    }
};

int main(int, char * a[]){
    Foo foo(1);
    Foo bar(2);
    std::cout << foo << std::endl;
    std::cout << bar<< std::endl;
    new(&bar)Foo(foo);
    std::cout << foo << std::endl;
    std::cout << bar << std::endl;

}
```

outputs

```
1
2
1
1
```

foo has been copied to bar using the placement new operator.

Answer (score 0):

Philosophically speaking, it looks as  safety-performance tradeoff. Const used for safety. As I understand, containers use assignment to reuse memory, i.e. for sake of performance. They would may use explicit destruction and placement new instead (and logicaly it is more correct), but assignment has a chance to be more efficient. I suppose, it is logically redundant requirement "to be assignable" (copy constructable is enough), but stl containers want to be faster and simpler.

Of course, it is possible to implement assignment as explicit destruction+placement new to avoid const_cast hack

Answer (score 0):

Rather than declaring the data-member `const`, you can make the public surface of the class `const`, apart from the implicitly defined parts that make it ([`semi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/semiregular))[`regular`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/regular).

```
class Multiply {
public:
    Multiply(double coef) : coef(coef) {}
    double operator()(double x) const {
        return coef*x;
    }
private:
    double coef;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

You basically never want to put a const member variable in a class. (Ditto with using references as members of a class.)

Constness is really intended for your program's control flow -- to prevent mutating objects at the wrong times in your code. So don't declare const member variables in your class's definition, rather make it all or nothing when you declare instances of the class.

Comment: This what I do, but it is not always possible. Think of some data gathering object with const parameters. You can't make the whole thing const, but many parameters within it can be const.

Comment: @m141, Depending on what you're trying to do, using const objects and defining certain fields with the `mutable` keyword may be appropriate. But in most situations, the most appropriate course of action is to make the whole object as being non-const. (The fact that some fields need to be const and others mutable suggests that you may need to break these fields up into different objects.)