# How can I overload the assignment operator if there is a private const member variable?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, constants

Can I overload the assignment operator for a class with a const member? The following class is a minimal example, in my case, there is a private const string. The copy constructor is straightforward.

If I cannot provide an assignment operator, what can I do to make the compiler warning C4512 go away?

```
class cTest
{
public:
  cTest();
  cTest(int i);
  cTest(const cTest & other);
  cTest & operator= (const cTest& other);
private:
  const int m_i;
};
```

EDIT: The question remains: If I cannot provide an assignment operator, what can I do to make the compiler warning C4512 go away? Why does the warning arise?

Comment: The dupe you received is valid.  For some followup look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/634662/non-static-const-member-cant-use-default-assignment-operator) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288190/constant-class-members-assignment-operator-and-qlist)

Comment: The warning is there because a const member implicitly deletes the copy-constructor and copy-assignment operator.