# Does C++ support STL-compatible immutable record types?

Tags: c++, constants, immutability, mutable

A number of languages have support for immutable types – once you have constructed the value of such a type, it cannot be modified in any way. I won't digress into the benefits of such types, as this has been discussed extensively elsewhere. (See e.g. http://codebetter.com/patricksmacchia/2008/01/13/immutable-types-understand-them-and-use-them/ )

I would like to create a lightweight immutable record type in C++. An obvious way of doing this would be to `const` all the members. For example:

```
struct Coordinates {
    const double x;
    const double y;
};
```

Unfortunately, a type declared in this way doesn't support copy assignment, and as such can't be used with STL containers, which is a pretty fatal drawback. I don't think there is any way around this, but would be grateful to know if anyone can see one.

For what it's worth, as far as I can see, C++ is conflating two things: a) whether you can assign a new value to a variable, and b) whether "values" (=objects) can be modified after they are constructed. The distinction is much clearer in e.g. Scala, where one has

- `val` vs `var`: a `var` can have a new value bound to it, a `val` cannot
- immutable and mutable objects, particularly collections

So I can write the following:

```
val val_mutable = collection.mutable.Map(1 -> "One")
val val_immutable = collection.immutable.Map(1 -> "One")
var var_mutable = collection.mutable.Map(1 -> "One")
var var_immutable = collection.immutable.Map(1 -> "One")
```

`var`s can be rebound to point at other values:

```
//FAILS: val_immutable = collection.immutable.Map(2 -> "Two")
//FAILS: val_mutable = collection.mutable.Map(2 -> "Two")
var_mutable = collection.mutable.Map(2 -> "Two")
var_immutable = collection.immutable.Map(2 -> "Two")
```

mutable collections can be modified:

```
val_mutable(2) = "Two"    
//FAILS: val_immutable(2) = "Two"    
var_mutable(2) = "Two"    
//FAILS: var_immutable(2) = "Two"
```

In C++, `const`ing the data members of a type makes it an immutable type but also makes it impossible to create "var"s of that type. Can anyone can see a reasonably lightweight way of achieving the former without the latter? [Please note the "lightweight" part -- in particular, I do not want to create an accessor function for every element of the `struct`, as this results in a massive drop in readability.]

Comment: "conflating two things", well, how would assigning a value to something not be modifying it?

Comment: Instead of making the members `const` for the drawbacks you mentioned, wouldn't it make more semantic sense to just make a `const Coordinates` object if you don't want it to be modified?

Comment: What about a regular `struct` but then declaring it `const`, like `const my_immutable_struct x{0,1};`?

Comment: @juanchopanza: there's a difference between modifying the variable (to bind to another value) and modifying the value itself.

Comment: No there isn't.

Comment: @CoryKramer @vsoftco This is a fallback option, but it's more verbose and (because you have to manually insert `const` in so many different places) less safe.

Comment: Well instead of saying `let immutable_type = ...;` (Swift) you say `const immutable_type = ... ;`, and without `const` your declaration is equivalent to `var mutable_type = ...;`. Maybe I don't understand exactly what you're trying to achieve (have to say I didn't read your link).

Comment: @Mohan C++ doesn't use reference semantics, by and large.

Comment: @juanchopanza: there is a _conceptual_ difference which is reflected in many programming languages, as I hope my examples showed, and (rather emphatically) in semantic analysis of programming languages. The difference may not be reflected in C++.

Comment: @Mohan the "conceptual difference in many programming languages" arises from them using reference semantics by default. In C++, use of the same functionality must be explicit, and is provided by pointers and pointer-like objects. You are attempting to have *reference-like* behavior while still explicitly stating your objects should be treated as *value-like*, when if you want reference-like behavior, you must explicitly state the members of your collection should behave in a reference-like way.

Comment: No, there isn't a conceptual difference reflected in many programming languages. Many programming languages choose to (partially) implement that concept, mainly to ease implementation of other useful things (e.g dynamic typing, polymorphism, etc..)

Comment: The difference between `val` and `var` in Scala, as far as I can tell from your example, is the difference between `T` and `T*` in C++. If you want to deal only in immutable objects, it would be the difference in `T const` and `T const*`. The first cannot be altered. The second, as a pointer, may be altered. The thing it points to may not. The second is the naked version of "many languages"' reference semantics, sans additional functionality like garbage collection or automatic reference counting.

Comment: Since with C++ you must manually manage the lifetimes of your variables, a more commonly used way of going about using reference semantics for immutable records in a container would be to use smart pointers to a `const T`, resulting in the value type of the container being `std::unique_ptr<T const>` or `std::shared_ptr<T const>`, for lightweight single owner cases and slightly heavier multiple owner cases, respectively, which is *exactly* what Brian is saying in his answer.

Comment: @jaggedSpire no, a `T` can be made to bind to a new value. E.g. `int a = 1; b = 2`, where `T` = `int`.

Comment: @Mohan that's mutating the variable. You're misunderstanding basic C++ concepts.

Comment: @jaggedSpire I'm not misunderstanding anything -- I'm giving a direct counterexample to what you wrote. You wrote that a `T` was like a `val`. I was pointing out that it wasn't, because C++ `int a = 1; a = 2` is legal but Scala `val a = 1; a = 2` isn't.

Comment: @Mohan I'm [really not sure how to make it clearer](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c2b20bd257a58331). Note that in many languages (like C#) data types like `int` are given value semantics, even if they usually follow reference semantics by default. [Here, value versus "pointer" semantics are explicitly referred to as different things.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/166039/4892076)

Comment: @jaggedSpire: I _understand_ how C++ works. I think we are repeatedly talking at cross purposes because you are thinking in terms of a memory model whereas I'm trying to express things in terms of a higher-level model of computational meaning. I have to use some non-C/C++ terminology and concepts to ask about this because the C/C++ terminology and concepts are inextricably tied to the system level and so some things are impossible to express in it -- but it's clearly not getting across and probably won't unless you have some familiarity with the denotational semantics. 

Let's stop.

Comment: @Mohan and just when it got interesting, too. :\ It seems to me sort of like ints in Scala are immutable, but yeah, I have a tendency to talk at cross purposes with people. Sorry for that. I'll stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention that you can't use the `Coordinates` class with STL containers as written with `const` members. The question of how to do that is answered (inconclusively) here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3372966/393816

The same suggestion, which is to make your instances `const` rather than your members, has been made in comment threads on this question too. I agree with your comment that it is less reliable since you must change more code, but perhaps you could use a typedef like so:

```
struct MutableCoordinates {
  double x;
  double y;
};

typedef const MutableCoordinates Coordinates;
```

So that users of `Coordinates` objects automatically get the immutable version unless they explicitly as for it? This would offset some of your worry about the verbosity of using the struct safely.

Of course, you can also switch to reference semantics by using `shared_ptr`, which will work very well with `const` objects since the different references can't mess with each other, but it comes with the overhead of manual memory allocation which is rather excessive for a struct of two `double`s.

Answer (score 7):

Remember that assignment in most other languages behaves like *pointer* reassignment in C++.

Thus, a `std::shared_ptr<const T>` in C++ has similar semantics to immutable types in other languages.

```
struct Coordinates {
    double x;
    double y;
};
std::shared_ptr<const Coordinates> p = std::make_shared<const Coordinates>(Coordinates{3.14, 42.0});
p->x *= 2;                                           // error; pointee is immutable
p = std::make_shared<const Coordinates>(Coordinates{6.28, 42.0}); // ok
```

Comment: You can bold the first phrase of your answer, as this is what users of other languages have difficulties to understand in their first forays in C++.

Comment: I know why it's happening (essentially because C++ structs are closer to the memory model of the computer than in other languages), but the question was whether I was missing some easy way around this.  So please excuse me if I don't accept this answer.

Comment: @Mohan I don't see other ways of doing it, so how about if you don't get other answers you accept it in the next days.

Comment: Great answer! I'd use `unique_ptr` instead as it's light (unless one needs reference counting).

Comment: _@Brian_ I'm rarely upvoting, but this deserves it.

Comment: Brian, since Mohan is after 'an easy way', how about some templates/typedefs on the line of a `declare_immutable<class T>` type (act as his `val` opposing `var`) and `make_immutable_collection<template <class T> coll_type>`. I'd do it, but your's is too nice of an answer to start another

Answer (score 1):

if you want to mimic your `var`/`val`, you may create 2 classes similar to:

```
template <typename T> class val
{
public:
    val(const T& t) : t(t) {}

    val(const val&) = default;
    val& operator = (const val&) = delete;

    const T* operator->() const { return &t; }
    const T& get() const { return t; }

    T* operator->() { return &t; }
    T& get() { return t; }

private:
    T t;
};

template <typename T> class var
{
public:
    var(const T& t) : t(t) {}

    var(const var&) = default;
    var& operator = (const var&) = default;
    var& operator = (const T&) { this->t = t; return *this; };

    const T* operator->() const { return &t; }
    const T& get() const { return t; }

    T* operator->() { return &t; }
    T& get() { return t; }

private:
    std::remove_const_t<T> t;
};
```

And then

```
val<const Coordinate> immutable_val({42, 51});
val<Coordinate> mutable_val({42, 51});
var<const Coordinate> immutable_var({42, 51});
var<Coordinate> mutable_var({42, 51});

//immutable_val->x = 42; // error
mutable_val->x = 42;
//immutable_var->x = 42; // error
mutable_var->x = 42;

//immutable_val = {42, 42}; // error
//mutable_val = {42, 42}; // error
immutable_var = {42, 42};
mutable_var = {42, 42};

//mutable_val = mutable_val; // error
//immutable_val = immutable_val; // error
immutable_var = immutable_var; 
mutable_var = mutable_var;
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/BfzOt6)